# Python. Error with remote_api, google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, remote-access

Following this guide:
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html

I edited my app.yaml, updated the app, and tried to connect using api_remote. Then I got this error. Why?

```
c:\python25\python "C:\Program Files
\Google\google_appengine\remote_api_shell.py" -s medmcqs.appspot.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\remote_api_shell.py", line 99,
in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\remote_api_shell.py", line 95,
in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\remote_a
pi_shell.py", line 140, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\remote_a
pi_shell.py", line 136, in main
    appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\remote_a
pi_shell.py", line 76, in remote_api_shell
    rpc_server_factory=rpc_server_factory)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api
\remote_api_stub.py", line 645, in ConfigureRemoteApi
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api
\remote_api_stub.py", line 501, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    'Invalid response recieved from server: %s' % response)
google.appengine.ext.remote_api.remote_api_stub.ConfigurationError: Invalid resp
onse recieved from server: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//
```

This is what my app.yaml looks like...

```
application: medmcqs
version: 2
runtime: python
api_version: 1

inbound_services:
- mail

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /options
  script: main.py

- url: /send
  script: main.py
  login: required

- url: /history
  script: main.py
  login: required

- url: /suggest
  script: main.py
  login: required

- url: .*
  script: main.py

builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

UPDATE: Here are the log details:

```
2012-01-18 01:40:33.659 /_ah/remote_api?rtok=252529974978 200 48ms 1kb Google-remote_api/1.0 win32/6.1.7601.2 Python/2.5.4.final.0
109.224.29.101 - - [18/Jan/2012:01:40:33 -0800] "GET /_ah/remote_api?rtok=252529974978 HTTP/1.1" 200 1605 - "Google-remote_api/1.0 win32/6.1.7601.2 Python/2.5.4.final.0" "medmcqs.appspot.com" ms=49 cpu_ms=23 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000855 instance=00c61b117cf891196f8b484d5951471ac52ac0
```

Comment: What does your app.yaml actually look like?

Comment: The rest of the error message just shows my html code

Comment: UPDATE: app.yaml is now included in the post

Comment: Somehow your app is serving responses for requests that should be directed to the remote_api builtin. Are you certain that the app.yaml you show is the one your app is currently running? What do your logs show for the remote_api requests?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure it is the same... log details added to the main topic...

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

modify the .* handler 
from :

```
-url: .*
 script: main.py
```

To:

```
-url: /.*
script: main.py
```

Or: Maybe you can manually add the handler and try again to see if there are any differences.

```
- url: /_ah/remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin
```

**EDIT1**

There is another version of remote console code that you may want to try try. It is also from google app engine official website.

```
#remote_console.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import code
import getpass
import sys

sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine")
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml\lib")
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib")

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from google.appengine.ext import db

def auth_func():
    return raw_input('Username:'), getpass.getpass('Password:')

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Usage: %s app_id [host]" % (sys.argv[0],)
app_id = sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    host = sys.argv[2]
else:
    host = '%s.appspot.com' % app_id

remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteDatastore(app_id, '/remote_api', auth_func, host)

code.interact('App Engine interactive console for %s' % (app_id,), None, locals())
```

Usage:

```
remote_console.py YOUR_APP_ID YOUR_APP_ID.appspot.com
```

or

```
remote_console.py s~YOUR_APP_ID YOUR_APP_ID.appspot.com
```

For some reason, some app id will begin with s~.

Comment: Tried both, still getting the same error...

Comment: @Hadi: I tried to upload your app.yaml to my server, and there is no such error. So I think the error should come from other places. Did you update your appengine SDK? Did you deploy your app correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your patience... I don't have a problem with uploading the app... I want to upload some data into my Data Store (since I can't seem to use sqlite) using api_remote (as they told me it is the way to go...)

Comment: @Hadi Sorry for confusing, I meant I upload your app.yaml to my app (only change the appId) and test with remote_api, so far everything is good.